# Recognise different sorting algorithms based on input data and runtime?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have been given a class with 5 methods (`sort1` to `sort5`) which I can't see. By giving an array as input to each method my task is to observe and find which sorting algorithm is implemented for each method (bubble sort, insertion sort, selection sort, merge sort or quick sort).

I have calculated the duration for arrays with 10k ,20k, 40k, 80k and 100k elements, each in ascending, descending and random order but I still can't figure it out.

This is my time calculation

```
sort1 ascen 10000 array (0.06400000 seconds)
sort1 ascen 20000 array (0.21700000 seconds)
sort1 ascen 40000 array (0.87100000 seconds)
sort1 ascen 80000 array (3.52100000 seconds)
sort1 ascen 100000 array (5.12500000 seconds)


sort1 dscen 10000 array (0.28900000 seconds)
sort1 dscen 20000 array (1.08200000 seconds)
sort1 dscen 40000 array (4.40100000 seconds)
sort1 dscen 80000 array (17.32000000 seconds)
sort1 dscen 100000 array (27.01900000 seconds)

sort1 random 10000 array (0.28100000 seconds)
sort1 random 20000 array (1.09300000 seconds)
sort1 random 40000 array (4.36800000 seconds)
sort1 random 80000 array (17.48700000 seconds)
sort1 random 100000 array (27.43300000 seconds)



sort2 ascen 10000 array (0.00300000 seconds)
sort2 ascen 20000 array (0.00200000 seconds)
sort2 ascen 40000 array (0.00300000 seconds)
sort2 ascen 80000 array (0.00200000 seconds)
sort2 ascen 100000 array (0.00300000 seconds)


sort2 dscen 10000 array (0.25700000 seconds)
sort2 dscen 20000 array (0.95800000 seconds)
sort2 dscen 40000 array (3.49500000 seconds)
sort2 dscen 80000 array (13.96100000 seconds)
sort2 dscen 100000 array (21.88800000 seconds)


sort2 random 10000 array (0.06100000 seconds)
sort2 random 20000 array (0.29000000 seconds)
sort2 random 40000 array (1.38100000 seconds)
sort2 random 80000 array (6.08200000 seconds)
sort2 random 100000 array (9.78800000 seconds)



sort3 ascen 10000 array (0.00500000 seconds)
sort3 ascen 20000 array (0.00100000 seconds)
sort3 ascen 40000 array (0.00900000 seconds)
sort3 ascen 80000 array (0.01900000 seconds)
sort3 ascen 100000 array (0.04800000 seconds)

sort3 dscen 10000 array (0.00700000 seconds)
sort3 dscen 20000 array (0.88100000 seconds)
sort3 dscen 40000 array (0.03000000 seconds)
sort3 dscen 80000 array (0.04100000 seconds)
sort3 dscen 100000 array (0.00600000 seconds)


sort3 random 10000 array (0.00200000 seconds)
sort3 random 20000 array (0.28400000 seconds)
sort3 random 40000 array (0.00700000 seconds)
sort3 ranodm 80000 array (0.01300000 seconds)
sort3 random 100000 array (0.01800000 seconds)


sort4 ascen 10000 array (0.01200000 seconds)
sort4 ascen 20000 array (0.01100000 seconds)
sort4 ascen 40000 array (0.00300000 seconds)
sort4 ascen 80000 array (0.09800000 seconds)
sort4 ascen 100000 array (0.05100000 seconds)

sort4 dscen 10000 array (0.00700000 seconds)
sort4 dscen 20000 array (0.00900000 seconds)
sort4 dscen 40000 array (3.50300000 seconds)
sort4 dscen 80000 array (0.00900000 seconds)
sort4 dscen 100000 array (0.01600000 seconds)



sort4 random 10000 array (0.00200000 seconds)
sort4 random 20000 array (0.00400000 seconds)
sort4 random 40000 array (1.37300000 seconds)
sort4 random 80000 array (0.01800000 seconds)
sort4 random 100000 array (0.02200000 seconds)



sort5 ascen 10000 array (0.00200000 seconds)
sort5 ascen 20000 array (0.00100000 seconds)
sort5 ascen 40000 array (0.00500000 seconds)
sort5 ascen 80000 array (0.00300000 seconds)
sort5 ascen 100000 array (0.00300000 seconds)


sort5 dscen 10000 array (0.25400000 seconds)
sort5 desc 20000 array (0.86900000 seconds)
sort5 desc 40000 array (3.53500000 seconds)
sort5 desc 80000 array (14.00900000 seconds)
sort5  desc 100000 array (21.85400000 seconds)



sort5 random 10000 array (0.28700000 seconds)
sort5 random 20000 array (1.28500000 seconds)
sort5 random 40000 array (5.84900000 seconds)
sort5 random 80000 array (25.92500000 seconds)
sort5  random  100000 array (41.10800000 seconds)
```

Comment: so, code that sorts your array.

Comment: Apply the 5 different sort methods into your class and call each sort method on each generated Array to see which sort method matches close to the duration time.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I'd say your timings are off in several cases. For example, the sort4 ascen takes 50 times longer for 40000 items than for 100000. There are several similar cases in your data.

In any case, the key here is to determine, for each sort, how the running time for random varies by the data size. For the sort algorithms you identified, it'll probably be n^2 or n*log(n). That gives you a good hint about the complexity of the algorithm. quicksort and merge sort are O(n log n), and the other three are O(n^2).

Then you take into account the best case and worst case behavior of those algorithms. For example, selection sort should have pretty close to the same running time in all three cases (ascending, descending, and random). Bubblesort and insertion sort have very good best-case (ascending) behavior. Merge sort has pretty consistent running time in all three cases. A naive Quicksort has terrible ascending or descending behavior, but is generally the fastest for a random list.

The whole idea is to test your understanding of the different sort algorithms' behaviors.